# How to add task to current method?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a web app similar to google calendar. I have done the object and methods within it but now it's time to be able to add what I want as a task. My idea is for the user to add something to the input and that input being console.logged for now.

Any idea?

HTML

```
<div class="new-task" id="task-input">
    <div id="add-new-task">Task: <input type="text"></div>
    <div id="add-time">Time: <input type="text"></div>
    <button class ="save-task" onclick="">Save task</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var idCounter = 0
var tasksManager = {
    array: [],
    add: function(task){

        taskObject = {
            title: task,
            idVerification: idCounter ++
        }
        tasksManager.array.push(taskObject)
    },
    show:function(id){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < tasksManager.array.length; i++) {
           if(id === tasksManager.array[i].idVerification){
            return tasksManager.array[i]
           }
        }
    },
    delete:function(task){
       if(this.show){
       tasksManager.array.splice(task)
       }
    }

}

var newTask = document.getElementById("add-new-task")
newTask.addEventListener('click',tasksManager.add())

console.log(tasksManager.array)
```

As you can see with console.log above the array index [0] is logged as undefined but I wanted the user to write in the input " Go to the gym" and this to be logged within the array.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Some issues:

1. You are not assigning the click handler. Instead you execute it *immediately* (not on click).
2. When you call `.add()` you don't provide an argument: the name of the task
3. The click handler should be on the button element, not on the `div` that has the `input` element. And so it will be useful to give that button an `id` attribute.
4. You should retrieve the value from the `input` element, and so it would be more appropriate to give *that* element an `id` and not so much the `div` that wraps it.
5. The `console.log` at the end of your script is executed immediately. It should be done only when the user has clicked the button.

Snippet with some corrections (also in the HTML!):

```js
var idCounter = 0
var tasksManager = {
    array: [],
    add: function(task){

        let taskObject = {
            title: task,
            idVerification: idCounter ++
        }
        tasksManager.array.push(taskObject)
    },
    show:function(id){
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < tasksManager.array.length; i++) {
           if(id === tasksManager.array[i].idVerification){
            return tasksManager.array[i]
           }
        }
    },
    delete:function(task){
       if(this.show){
       tasksManager.array.splice(task)
       }
    }

}

var button = document.getElementById("save-task"); // <-- the button
var input = document.getElementById("add-new-task"); // <-- the input (move the ID attribute to the input!)
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    tasksManager.add(input.value);
    console.log(tasksManager.array)
})
```

```html
<div class="new-task" id="task-input">
    <div >Task: <input id="add-new-task" type="text"></div>
    <div id="add-time">Time: <input type="text"></div>
    <button class ="save-task" id ="save-task" onclick="">Save task</button>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry that still gives me undefined

Comment: Yes, there were several other issues in your script. See update of my answer.